# Use of 'of that'

Tags: relative-pronouns

I came across this line

> This is the boy that I told you of.

Can I use 'of' with 'that' in this way:

> This is the boy of that I told you.

Can I also replace 'that' with 'whom' in  this way:

> This is the boy whom I told you of.

Comment: Instaead of _of_, I would use _about_. And no, the word-juggling does not work, _This is the boy of that I told you_ is not grammatical (it's hardly understandable). Why would you want to juggle those words like that? Please don't tell me it's because of that silly _don't end a sentence with a preposition_ nonsense that you hear so much about!

Comment: No, and the reason is that _that_ is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun like "who", "whom", "which" etc.

Comment: _This is the boy of whom I told you._

Comment: @mplungjan You want to say that you can use preceding preposition with all relative pronouns except that.Is it?

Comment: @ashish7249 https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/150313/364

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a blanket "no" that will come from the team that says you cannot end a sentence with a preposition. I don't play for that team, and accept your initial sentence.  I'm ok with or without the "that", but I prefer economy. However, "This is the boy of that I told you." does not work at all for me.  It encourages me to "correct" with "This is the boy I told you about", but "of" works too, just not my first choice.
I am also one who finds the use of "whom" quite forced, and would avoid it in most cases. So, if the question is whether it sounds natural, I would say no.  Wrong?, maybe not, perhaps better to ask somebody who feels comfortable using "whom" in other situations (aside from standard statements like "To Whom It May Concern").

Comment: The crucial point is that *"This is the boy of that I told you" is ungrammatical because "that" is not a relative pronoun like "who", "whom" etc. but a subordinator.

Answer (score 1):

Once you recognize that "whom" is still a valid word in English (though often misused), there is a very simple way to re-write. However, my feeling is that "whom" is best used close to the verb or preposition of which it is the object because English is no longer a language that syntactically depends on inflection.

I agree with another answer that "talked about" sounds less stilted than "told you of."

Correct and unstilted versions are:

**This is the boy that I talked about.**

**This is the boy about whom I talked.**

Correct (but somewhat stilted to my ear):

**This is the boy that I told you of.**

**This is the boy of whom I told you.**

**This is the boy whom I told you of.** (I myself would definitely not write this.)

Incorrect

**This is the boy of that I told you.**